# Is there anyway to embed a youtube video in powerpoint on  64 bit windows 7?

Tags: video, 64-bit, microsoft-powerpoint, youtube

I am looking for a solution to embed a youtube video into a powerpoint slide  I have windows 7 64 bit edition with office 64 bit.

Is this possible.  Searched around google for ages and can't find a solution for this.

Comment: see here: http://think.stedwards.edu/computerhelp/powerpoint2010knownissuesandsolutions

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [this](http://think.stedwards.edu/computerhelp/powerpoint2010knownissuesandsolutions) should work:

> **Known Issue:** Using 64-bit PowerPoint 2010 "Insert Video from a Website" is disabled.
>
> **Solution:** To enable "Insert Video From Website" using 64-bit PowerPoint 2010 you must install the latest Adobe Flash Player 11.
>
> - Step 1: Choose "Windows 7 (64-bit)"
> - Step 2: Install BOTH versions - "Flash Player 11 for Internet Explorer" AND "Flash Player 11 for Other Browsers"
>
> **Outcome:** Once the active-x is installed a user will be able to insert a video from a website.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

After searching the desired Video, you want to upload. First thing you want to do is click on the Share button. Doing this will open up more options underneath the YouTube. The HTML code would also appear in Text Box. Then simply click on Embedded Button. You might also need to change the default size of the video preview. This is an important setting to consider in order to obtain a professional looking blog. After setting the video options as desired, it is time to embed the video you have chosen. Simply navigate to your WordPress administrator panel (/wp-admin section) and while editing a blog post switch to the HTML editor by clicking on the HTML button. Paste the HTML Code, appeared and publish.